# Whats the better way of doing this

Tags: python

I've only been coding in python for a month and I tried making something that searches for duplicates in a user made list...

```
List = []
count = 0 
Val = 0 
usernum = int(input("How many numbers are in your list: "))

for i in range(0, usernum): 
    values = int(input("What is the number on the list: "))
    List.append(values)

for i in range(0, len(List)):
    if List[i] == List[Val]:
        print("There are duplicates")
        count += 1
        if count == len(List):
            Val += 1
            continue
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? Is it good already? I mean: does it even give you the correct result?

Comment: Is there an issue or error?

Comment: you can detect duplicates using a python set():   if len(set(List)) != len(List): print('we have at least one duplicate item')

Comment: or use a collections.Counter to get counts for each unique item in the list, and check for non-1 entries

Comment: @ThomasWeller Well I thought there might be a better way since the way im doing it felt crude, it prints "there are duplicates" every time it finds a pair of numbers that are duplicates.

Comment: @AbbeGijly oh, does set have the same length as all unique digits in the array?

Comment: Your code wont work. you are iterating over the list and comparing always to `List[Val]` where Val is 0 at the beginning. So if the duplicate is not the first element your code won't find it.

Comment: yes -- set([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2])  returns {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki if I enter the values 1,2,5,0,5 it does detect 5 to be the duplicate though

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry, the indentation is a formatting error from me, and I left out list while copy pasting.. sorry!!!!

Comment: I corrected the indentation of your code, add an initialization of List=[]  and tried you example values `1,2,5,0,5`. It doesnt detect any duplicate as expected. your code will not detect duplcates fo the values `1,2,5,0,5`

Comment: 'without initializing List=[] it cannot run. You are not posting all the code here.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thankfully, `i` starts at 0, and `List[0]` equals itself, so it **always** detects a "duplicate" :-) (unless the list is empty)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yeah sorry I just fixed that

Comment: @KellyBundy no it doesn't. only if the first element is repeated. otherwise it doesnt

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Well you're wrong. Please show exactly what you tried.

Comment: Don't care about the votes. It's because of the indentation and your code did not run at all initially. Next time, test the code on your machine and make sure it runs. This will also help us to reproduce it more easily.

Comment: @ThomasWeller alright :) thanks for the help mate, have a good one

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Or see point 2 in Thomas' answer.

Comment: Don't become afraid of asking. All the best for your your programming career.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work for various reasons:

1. You're missing your main variable: the list. Add it like this

   ```
   List = []
   ```

   BTW: `List` with a capital L is not an awesome choice, but still a much better choice than `list` with a lower case L which could cause all kinds of problems.
2. With that added, enter `1` and `1` and you'll find that even for a single number it will print "There are duplicates". That is because you compare

   ```
   List[i] == List[Val]
   ```

   where both `i` and `Val` are 0. The item compares against itself. That must no be the case.
3. All the if-logic is weird. It's unclear to me what you wanted to achieve. A common approach would be a nested loop in order to compare each item against each following item. Note how `j` starts at `i+1`

   ```
   for i in range(0, len(List)):
       for j in range(i+1, len(List)):
           if List[i] == List[j]:
               print("There are duplicates")
   ```

An even better approach would be to not implement that yourself at all but use other techniques like

```
if len(set(List)) < len(List):
    print("There are duplicates")
```

where `set()` will give you the unique numbers only. If numbers have been removed because they were not unique (aka. duplicate), that set will have less numbers than the list.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just realized I hadn't copied the List initialization and fixed that. And thankyou for that for loop, I was looking for how to do that and the weird if's I used it all I could think of, i didnt realise i could've just used two for loops with one in the other

Comment: Could use `usernum` instead of `len(List)` (not sure what's better... If they had called it the common `n` then I would certainly prefer that)

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can vote it up. If it solved your problem, please check the checkmark so others do not invest time to provide more solutions.

Comment: @KellyBundy: this time I chose to have my code more similar to OPs code so he recognizes where it must go. I didn't want to change too much.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't even talking about that one, I meant the `set` solution (which is very different from theirs anyway).

Comment: @ThomasWeller i would upvote but i dont have enough rep yet lol

Comment: @StopThis: no problem. I have enough ;-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: ok, I see. Still not using it because `usernum` is not a very good name does not reflect that it has something to do with the length of the list.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thankyou sm for the amazing help and the not deserved updoot :)